# CSS :before not displaying

Tags: css, css-selectors

How do you get the :before pseudoclass to render properly? Do I need some special CSS to make this work?

This does not work and does not display anything: 
http://jsfiddle.net/XzMH6/

HTML

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

CSS

```
#test:before{
    width:100px; height:100px; background: #ddd;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: not really sure what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: It would be helpful if you described the problem with more detail. What specific problem do you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `content` property.

```
#test:before{
    width:100px; height:100px; background: #ddd;
    display:block;
    content: "";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ULfeu/

Answer (score 0):

try this

please add this  `content:""` in `#test` class then `:before` is working properly

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XzMH6/1/)